# How to use BCrypt / Bcryptjs in Angular?

Tags: angular, bcrypt

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.css']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }


  val = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
    username: '',
    password: ''
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  isDisplay = false;
  toggleDisplay() {
    this.isDisplay = !this.isDisplay;
  }

  onSubmit(v: NgForm) {
    console.log(v.value, v.valid);
    console.log(this.val);

    // const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    // const pass = bcrypt.hashSync(this.val.password, salt);
    //delete const if not working
  }
}
```

We are required to use BCrypt for our project in university. I would like to know how to console.log or to check if the password that is already hashed.

I already installed `npm install bcryptjs` and `npm install @types/bcrypt`

Thank you!

Comment: There's no way for you to tell if a user-submitted password is already hashed, if that's what you mean. For all you know, it's a plaintext password that looks like a hash. And even if it were already hashed by the user/client, you'd want to hash is again at the server. If these facts are not clear to you, please consult your course materials or your instructor.

Comment: Ok thank you so much! We're still about to discuss hashing in the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a frontend framework, and hence can be spoofed by end users. You should NEVER EVER trust users' inputs, so Angular is NOT a place where you check the hash status of a password. Instead, you should do it in the server. The [`bcryptjs` library](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js) exposes `compare()` function which can be used to compare the plain password against hashed one. And if this functions returns `true`, the given password is considered correct.

Example:

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
bcrypt.compare('<plain_password>', '<hashed_password>').then((isCorrect) => {
  console.log(isCorrect); // should be true for correct password, false otherwise
});
```

Comment: While it's true that hashing should be done at the server instead of the client, the reasons have nothing to do with spoofing or trust. Rather, it's the fact that, if the password is being hashed at the client, then this hash effectively becomes a plaintext password. This is true whether or not the client is well-behaved/trustworthy.

Comment: I just wanted to check if I did it right. will do try this, thank you so much!

Comment: No you didn't. Assuming you'll run it on server (since that's what I suggested), using **sync** functions are considered bad practice. Use **async** ones instead (`genSalt()` and `hash()`). Second, you don't need to generate any salt, `hash()` function accepts number as second argument too, so you can pass `10` there (effectively reducing one extra line) or leave it empty for picking up `12` as default.